# What is the correct SQLAlchemy equivalent to this SQLite statement?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, subquery

I'm trying to get the latest changes of each team.

**SQLite statement**
Works as expected.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM team_history ORDER BY changed_at DESC
) sub GROUP BY team
```

**SQLAlchemy implementation**
For whatever reason I've to sort with `asc()` instead of `desc()` to get the same result, that's why I doubt my implementation is correct.

```py
session.query(TeamHistory)\
    .select_entity_from(
        session.query(TeamHistory).order_by(asc(TeamHistory.changed_at)).subquery()
    ).group_by(TeamHistory.team)\
    .all()
```

**Environment**

Python: 3.8.0
SQLAlchemy: 1.3.23

**Reproducing**

Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "team_history" (ID integer PRIMARY KEY, changed_at TEXT, team TEXT);
```

Records:

```py
[{"ID":1,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":2,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":3,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:30:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":4,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":5,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 11:30:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":6,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":7,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 11:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":8,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":9,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":10,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":11,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":12,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":13,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":14,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 12:30:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":15,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":16,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 12:00:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":17,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":18,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 13:30:00","team":"A"},
 {"ID":19,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},
 {"ID":20,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"}]
```

**Solution**
Thanks everyone!

```
session.query(TeamHistory)\
    .group_by(TeamHistory.team)\
    .having(func.max(TeamHistory.changed_at))\
    .all()
```

Comment: Thanks, @rfkortekaas. If the code above is correct, it must be my set up. Do you have an idea what it could be? Maybe a misconfiguration?

Comment: You can also use `echo=True` in your `create_engine()` call to see the SQL statements that are being emitted.

Comment: @rfkortekaas Thanks a lot for your help! I noticed one difference: in my model I'm using `changed_at = Column(DateTime)`. I'll try your example asap.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I ran your example and got `20` and `19`. After replacing `desc` with `asc` I get `18` and `5`. We're running the same code with the same data and get different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
GROUP BY somecolumn
```

SQLite returns 1 row for each distinct value of `somecolumn`, but which row?
The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) states that the row is undefined, meaning it is chosen arbitrarily, although from my experience it seems that the 1st row in the resultset belonging to each group will be returned.
But this is not guaranteed and queries like the one above and your query should be avoided.

There are a number of ways to get for each `team` the row with the latest `changed_at`.
One of them, which is valid in SQLite (although it would not work in other databases) is:

```
SELECT * FROM team_history GROUP BY team HAVING MAX(changed_at)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fc599cd6c8e19a2c45f0bb9976b164c2).
So, this is the query that you should translate to SQLAlchemy (I can't help you with that).

There are other ways also, using window functions, or `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. The following SQLAlchemy implementation works: `session.query(TeamHistory).group_by(TeamHistory.team).having(func.max(TeamHistory.changed_at)).all()`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the query that you proposed should work. SQLite stores dates as strings in the ISO-8601 format which has the property that lexicographical and chronological ordering are the same. Also using the datetime column as `TEXT` has the same properties.

So the ordering `desc` from the subquery should result in the following:

| ID | DateTime | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 2021-03-02 13:30:00 | A |
| 14 | 2021-03-02 12:30:00 | A |
| 16 | 2021-03-02 12:00:00 | A |
| 5 | 2021-03-02 11:30:00 | B |
| .. | .. | .. |

As stated in the other answer the issue with group by is that is chooses the returned row for each group arbitrarily but it looks like it is always the first row. Knowing this we have different solutions to be sure which rows it should return:

```py
# Using an aggregate function in select
session.query(TeamHistory.team, func.max(TeamHistory.changed_at)).group_by(TeamHistory.team).all()

# Using an aggregate function with `having`
session.query(TeamHistory).group_by(TeamHistory.team).having(func.max(TeamHistory.changed_at).all()
```

This results in the following working example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, Text, DateTime, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, deferred, column_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import datetime

Base = declarative_base()

class TeamHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team_history'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    changed_at = Column(DateTime)
    team = Column(Text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    db = Session()
    
    lst = [{"ID":1,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":2,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":3,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:30:00","team":"B"},{"ID":4,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":5,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 11:30:00","team":"B"},{"ID":6,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":7,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 11:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":8,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":9,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":10,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":11,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":12,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":13,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":14,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 12:30:00","team":"A"},{"ID":15,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":16,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 12:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":17,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":18,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 13:30:00","team":"A"},{"ID":19,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":20,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"}]
    for dct in lst:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dct.get('changed_at'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        nth = TeamHistory(id=dct.get('ID'), changed_at=dt, team=dct.get('team'))
        db.add(nth)

    db.commit()

    res = db.query(TeamHistory)\
        .select_entity_from(
            db.query(TeamHistory).order_by(TeamHistory.changed_at.desc()).subquery()
        ).group_by(TeamHistory.team)\
        .all()

    for r in res:
        print(r.id, r.changed_at, r.team)
    print()


    res = db.query(TeamHistory)\
        .group_by(TeamHistory.team)\
        .having(func.max(TeamHistory.changed_at))\
        .all()

    for r in res:
        print(r.id, r.changed_at, r.team)
    print()

    res = db.query(TeamHistory.id, func.max(TeamHistory.changed_at), TeamHistory.team)\
        .group_by(TeamHistory.team)\
        .all()

    for r in res:
        print(r[0], r[1], r[2])
```

If you are mainly interested in the last change of the team you can also use `deferred` and `column_property` to only get `MAX(changed_at)`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, Text, DateTime, func, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, deferred, column_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import datetime

Base = declarative_base()

class TeamHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team_history_def'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    changed_at = deferred(Column(DateTime))
    last_changed = column_property(func.max(changed_at))
    team = Column(Text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    db = Session()
    
    lst = [{"ID":1,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":2,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":3,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:30:00","team":"B"},{"ID":4,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":5,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 11:30:00","team":"B"},{"ID":6,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":7,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 11:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":8,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":9,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":10,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":11,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":12,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":13,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":14,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 12:30:00","team":"A"},{"ID":15,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":16,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 12:00:00","team":"A"},{"ID":17,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":18,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 13:30:00","team":"A"},{"ID":19,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"B"},{"ID":20,"changed_at":"2021-03-02 10:00:00","team":"A"}]
    for dct in lst:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dct.get('changed_at'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        nth = TeamHistory(id=dct.get('ID'), changed_at=dt, team=dct.get('team'))
        db.add(nth)

    db.commit()

    res = db.query(TeamHistory)\
        .group_by(TeamHistory.team)\
        .all()

    for r in res:
        print(r.id, r.changed_at, r.team)
    print()
```